# How to change the Bot/Skype channel incoming message text format

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, skype

Bot emulator works fine with the clear text responses but when I try to do the same via Skype the bot response with;

> I don't understand, please try again

I found out that Skype auto-formats the email by wrapping it in `<a />` tags - XMM format and I am a bit stuck what's supposed to do. I think changing the incoming text format to plain-text would fix this.

I found this like for a [similar issue on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1405) but this is on C# and I am using Node.JS.

How do I change the default text format of the bot/skype channel to plain text instead of markdown so Skype auto-formatting would not happen?

**Updated** according to [@ezequiel-jadib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44454525/257727) but still no luck. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

```
// bot.js
bot.use(...[logger]);

// logger.js
module.exports = exports = {
    receive: (e, next) => {
        e.textFormat('plain');
        logConversation(e);
        next();
    },
    send: (e, next) => {
        logConversation(e);
        next();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you filter by channel, then add some REGEX?

Comment: I don't know how to do that and the only examples I found about channels is done for facebook and there were some stuff related to those on the .NET track but not on Node.JS.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this situation, you need to validate if you have an HTML wrapped email address, then extract the email portion from the string before saving it to `session.dialogData`.

For example replace [line 40](https://github.com/99xt/jira-journal/blob/master/bot/modules/dialogs/signin.js#L40):

```
const usernameOrEmail = session.dialogData.usernameOrEmail = results.response;
```

with:

```
// where results.response is in the format '<a href="hello@world.com">hello@world.com</a>'
var exampleEmailWrappedInHtml = results.response;

// validate if we have email wrapped in HTML from Skype
if(exampleEmailWrappedInHtml.match(/<a href="mailto:/i)) {
    console.log('HTML wrapped email detected!');
    const usernameOrEmail = session.dialogData.usernameOrEmail = exampleEmailWrappedInHtml.split('>')[1].split('<')[0];
} else {
    console.log('no match.');
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work since it never reaches line 40. The bot response is originating from the Luis Intent, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call to the [textFormat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/e26ea2404724238ac64c701e493c0f005b0f3444/Node/core/src/Message.ts#L110) method of the `Message` like in `C#`

The accepted values are:

`export var TextFormat = {
    plain: 'plain',
    markdown: 'markdown',
    xml: 'xml'
};`

Comment: At what point do I have to set this? I tried it on `bot.use` middleware but didn't work.